# CommentThreads amount changes by order

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

CommentThreads amount changes by order

Hi I'm trying to fetch all comments of a video. For testing purpose I'm using this video Id U55NGD9Jm7M.

When I order by time I get 1538 comments the last wrote on the 02.05.2015.
If I’m using the relevance I only receive 1353 comment and the last was wrote on the 29.04.2015

This doesn’t seem right to me. I expected to receive the same comments but in a different order and not different comments.
I also tried this on a different video and the results were the same.

My code cut down to minimum

Thank you for your help

```
public class foo
{
    public void bar(string videoId)
    {
        var allTopLevelComments = new List<CommentThread>();

        var searchListResponse = getThread(videoId);
        allTopLevelComments.AddRange(searchListResponse.Items);

        string nextPage = searchListResponse.NextPageToken;
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPage))
        {
            searchListResponse = getThread(videoId, searchListResponse.NextPageToken);
            nextPage = searchListResponse.NextPageToken;
            allTopLevelComments.AddRange(searchListResponse.Items);
        }

        var first = allTopLevelComments.OrderBy(c => c.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.PublishedAt).First();
    }

    private CommentThreadListResponse getThread(string videoId, string nextPageToken = "")
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                ApiKey = "my key",
                ApplicationName = "my app"
            });

        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.CommentThreads.List("id, replies, snippet");
        searchListRequest.VideoId = videoId;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 100;
        searchListRequest.Order = CommentThreadsResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum.Time;
        searchListRequest.TextFormat = CommentThreadsResource.ListRequest.TextFormatEnum.PlainText;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nextPageToken))
        {
            searchListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
        }

        return searchListRequest.Execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I look at that video, I see that there are 8000+ comments, with the latest one posted yesterday. Where did you get this code?

Comment: I wrote the code myself. My question is misleading. I wrote 'When I order by time I get 1538 comments the last wrote on the 02.05.2015. If I’m using the relevance I only receive 1353 comment and the last was wrote on the 29.04.2015' actually meant to say the oldest comment I receive was written on that date.

As you can see var first = allTopLevelComments.OrderBy(c => c.Snippet.TopLevelComment.Snippet.PublishedAt).First(); 

I’m ordering the TopLevelComment’s by pulishedAt and grab only the first.